Extract tar file and copy/replace its files to another location
I have a .TAR file containing a folder named data.
The data folder contains a LOT of files and subfolders and also some that are hidden.
I have to copy this 1 on 1 to another location. Existing files need to be replaced.
Is this the right way? I see that it's not quite working yet in Home assistant and I don't understand why. I think that it skips some files.
tar -xf /share/nas/homeassistant.tar -C /home/docker/test

sudo cp -a /home/docker/test/data/. /home/docker/homeassistant/data/

Am I forgetting something?

Instead of cp you might try rsync: rsync -av /home/docker/test/data /home/docker/homeassistant/

Why not extract the tar file directly to that other location?
